# htaccess to handle redirect page when url encodeURIComponent

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I have a page that uses TinyMCE to update the contents of the web. when I click the button on the form with ajax post method, I get the contents of my url like this (http://vansolusindo.com/demo2/lapakkemasan/test/test.php?v_content=%3Cp%3Etest+update+data%3C% 2Fp% 3E & save = Submit).

then immediately redirect to the index page of my website. so it makes no .php file for input to the database. My question, how to handle that my page is not redirect to the index page and enter .php pages to insert into the database.

- I've been looking on the internet, there seems to be a setting for his .htaccess file.

The following script .php and my .htaccess.

script test.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<script>
 function umce(){ 
    tinyMCE.triggerSave()
    }; 
 function ut(){   
    $.ajax({  
        cache: false,
        type:'POST', 
        url:'save.php',  
        data:"text="+encodeURIComponent(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent()), 
        success: function(data){
                alert(1);
        }
    }); 
    return false; 
};
</script>    
<script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea' });</script>
</head>
<body>
<form onsubmit='umce();ut(); return false;'>
<textarea id="v_content" name="v_content"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="save" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

save.php :

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("lapakkemasandb");
$sql="UPDATE t_modules SET content=('$_POST[v_content]') WHERE id_t_modules='3'";
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "success to update"; 
mysql_close($con) 
?>
```

.htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

## Please help me, I've been dizzy =( =( =(

Comment: Your submit button submit the form. instead of submit used the button and click on button to call the ajax or used the preventDefault to stop the form to post on other page

Comment: So, what I need to improve?

Comment: function ut(e){   
e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({  
        cache: false,
        type:'POST', 
        url:'save.php',  
        data:"text="+encodeURIComponent(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent()), 
        success: function(data){
                alert(1);
        }
    }); 
    return false;

Comment: hey @NavjotSingh, when i see with firebug in coloumn NET, i get 3 proses page. 1 GET test.php, 2 POST save.php, 3.GET Page Index in my website for example GET vansolusindo.com. And when i see Response from page save.php this content from vansolusindo.com(index page) not to update database. So, what I do?