# set session from jquery to session in php

Tags: php, jquery

i have a page in php to execute query. when i need the parameter from another page with session using jquery. so, how to set session in php from session in jquery. please check my code and give me solution. thanks...

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.ciphertrick.com/demo/jquerysession/js/jquerysession.js?d56ac9"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
var sDecode = $.session.get("sesDecode"); 
alert(sDecode);      
}); 
</script> 
<?php
include('connection.php');  
$content= ==> how to get " sDecode " ???
$upd = mysql_query("UPDATE t_modules set content='$content' where id_t_modules='3'") or die(mysql_error());  
?>
```

Comment: You need to use AJAX to get the PHP session variable.

Comment: jQuery sessions have nothing to do with PHP sessions.

Comment: actual data I can is the content of a TinyMCE textarea. if possible to pass parameters by ajax if the value sent is too long? therefore I save the session

Comment: may be you can view this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39952486/htaccess-to-handle-redirect-page-when-url-encodeuricomponent , this is real my case .. please...

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax to send parameter to a php file like this

```
$.ajax({
        url: "connection.php", 
        data: "Session="+$.session.get("sesDecode"), 
        type: "POST", 
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (e) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
        },
        error:function(e){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that both solutions needs you to **check the input** since the user could potentially modify it.

### Using Ajax

The best way to get `sDecode` is probably to send it via [jQuery.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) (AJAX) to a PHP page that will register the session value (after doing the appropriate checks to it).

```
$.post('session.php', { d: sDecode }, function (response) {
      alert(response);
});
```

and you get it in PHP via :

```
$sDecode = $_POST["d"]; // Please test the input here!
```

You might have to use `.serialize()` and then unserialize it in PHP depending on the content and how you treat it.

### Using Redirection

You can simply redirect to a page and transmit it directly as a GET value:

```
window.location.href=”session.php?d="+sDecode;
```

Then on the session.php page you would read it using this code :

```
$sDecode = $_GET["d"]; // Please test the input here!
```

Answer (score -1):

You can have PHP fill in the Javascript variable from the session variable.

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<html>
...
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var sDecode = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['sDecode']); ?>;
    alert(sDecode);
</script>
```

Comment: I think he is actually asking for the opposite way around (from jQuery to PHP), but your answer makes sense as well since the question is not clear.

Answer (score -1):

PHP execute before Jquery so use ajax after get the parameter from session to do your query

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, it would have been better to post as a comment.

Comment: No worries @Samir Nabil, we are all trying (this is only an advice for the next times) :-)